# JavaScript doesn't recognize code after import

Tags: javascript, import

When I remove the import line, all works fine (except that it doesn't find the imported functions, of course). But when I take the import in, it says "Uncaught ReferenceError: myFunction is not defined".

```
import io from 'socket.io-client';

function myFunction(name) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        mydel(name)

    }, 2000);
    print(name);
    sendOrder(name);
}
```

(I took the rest of the code out)

Am I doing some syntax wrong? Couldn't find the error

Comment: The error message "Uncaught ReferenceError: myFunction is not defined" occurs when you try to call the function. You haven't shown us how you call myFunction. You've only shown us a definition. Please include a good deal more code. Is myFunction in a module? Is it trying to call something from socket.io-client? There is not enough information provided here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using:

```
const io = require('socket.io-client');
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you use Node to run this Code or you want to run this code on the other environments? 
if it's node, check your node version with this command:

`node -v`

your node must support `import` Keyword

don't forget to call Function, maybe it's your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try out this method ,

```
Step 1 ) npm i socket.io-client --save

Step 2 ) 
    import ioClient from 'socket.io-client'

    let io = ioClient('http://your-host');
```

For more details , visit the [npm documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io-client) and another [git hub](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client/issues/1055) solutoin